# Access ViewData dictionary from custom metadata provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a custom metadata provider that inherits from `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`. I am wondering how (if possible) I add data to the `ViewData` dictionary from the custom metadata provider class?

Comment: There's no connection between the two systems. What scenario are you trying to enable?

Comment: @Marcind - Thanks for the reply. I ended up using the metadata.AdditionalValue dictionary to solve the problem. You would know by chance how to add RegEx based validation via metadata provider?